# Um site consegue ver quais guias estão abertas no meu navegador, ou se outros navegadores estão abertos?

Tags: javascript, monitoramento

Olá, não sou nenhum expert em programação, apesar de achar bem interessante, apenas estou preocupado com a minha privacidade em uma situação específica, e encontrei esse site a partir da minha dúvida, a questão é: 
Um site consegue ver o que faço em outras guias do meu navegador? ou até mesmo em outro navegador? se sim, como impedir que isso ocorra?

Comment: Não............